# postgres plpgsql parameter text max length

Tags: c, postgresql, plpgsql

I've a function that take text as input.
Notice the parameter max length is 256.
How Can I pass a longer text?

Example code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Test(nameid text)
.... # do something # ....
```

I've got error if length nameid > 256 because of `\0` not present at the end.
So I suppose postgres truncate (`strcat_s`?) the parameter.
Is there a **simple** way to pass a parameter text of arbitrary length?

I've already tried `varchar(1024)` instead of `text` and it's not working. Same results: truncate at 256 char.

**EDIT**

I'm using in combinations with **SPI** lib.
I call the plpg function from a C code.
The error for 256 was mine (need a break).
I used a `strcpy_s` with 256 char limits :\ **[Solved]**

Comment: The truncate must happen somewhere else. `text` is virtually unlimited (1GB). Please show us a complete example. Where did you get that from that the max. parameter length is 256?

Comment: See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/15e9c/5 the returned value is 500 characters long

Comment: I vote to close, because this question is not going to help anyone. Just a misunderstanding.

Comment: Voted to close as well

Answer (score -1):

When creating function in Postgresql you just specify "character varying" is the same as using "text" for a text parameter and you should be able to use much more than 256 characters...

For exemple:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aaa.function_name(integer, character varying)
RETURNS refcursor AS...
```

Regards

Comment: You *can* specify `text` as the parameter type as well.

Comment: `character` is nonsense. Don't do this. I quote the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html): `character without length specifier is equivalent to character(1)`

Comment: Sorry I meant "character varying" and not just "character". According to Postgresql doc, if character varying is used without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size. Character varying and text are mostly the same...